# Android - Button not 100% transparent

Tags: android, button, drawable

I have added the following button in my XML file:

```
<Button
    style="@style/RoundedButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:text="Say Hi" />
```

The following is what the `rounded_button` background looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

The following is the `RoundedButton` style:

```
<style name="RoundedButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/md_blue_700</item>
</style>
```

The following is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the background of the entire layout is blue. But for some reason, the button has a different shade of blue at either end. Why is this? How can I get it to be truly transparent and just show the background?

Comment: does that behaviour change when you use `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content` as width and height?

Comment: can u show the RoundedButton style

Comment: On what android version you are testing? Becase your code is working fine on 5.1.1 without a style.

Comment: The easy (and perhaps the only) way to do it is just to change the @android:color/transparent to actual background color (in this case blue).

Comment: @PaulZin I have tried that and it has the same effect. @AlNoman I have added the `RoundedButton` style.

Comment: Well it's working fine at me after added your style. Try to remove the background attribute from style.

Comment: @PaulZin I did that, still got the same problem :(

Comment: @Subby Look, I deleted RoundedButton style in Button and in rounded_button.xml I changed transparent color to @color/accent_material_light. And here's the [**result**](http://i.imgur.com/PoFT5A3.png)

Comment: Ah I see. That worked! Please post it as an answer and I shall mark it as the answer. Though...I hate the fact that `transparent` didn't work.

Comment: It appears that only in API level 22 do the extra shade of blue appear. In previous versions, it works perfectly fine.